# HTML Canvas style sizing vs native sizing performance

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm building a small game that uses 8-bit style art. I want to size the rendering canvas up but wonder if it's better using css or native. Which would be better performance?

I'm using a small canvas to draw and then render on a larger canvas for display.

CSS:

```
<style>
#render_canvas {
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  image-rendering: optimizeSpeed;
  image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges;
  image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast;
  image-rendering: optimize-contrast;
  image-rendering: pixelated;
  -ms-interpolation-mode: nearest-neighbor;   
}
</style>
```

or

Native:

```
canvas.id = 'render_canvas';
canvas.width = 600;
canvas.height = 600;

canvay.ctx.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
canvas.ctx.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
canvas.ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
```

Comment: Are you sizing the Canvas up to create the large pixels of 8-bit graphics? You probably aren't going to get your desired effect because the canvas will smooth between pixels and generally look gross

Comment: canvas image smoothing is not really reliable / supported well.

Comment: Correct, and the size up looks great, no blur. With both methods.